# Inserting NULL into column?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how I can insert a NULL value into a column of newly inserted row.

I'm working on "post icons" which will display a small icon for the thread on the thread list. The icons use RADIO buttons in the form. By default it is set to No Icon. I was wondering what to do for the value of that radio button to make it null? I tried setting value as NULL but it just inserts the word "NULL" into the database.

```
            $thread_sql = "
            INSERT INTO forum_threads (
                user_id,
                forum_id,
                thread_postdate,
                thread_lastpost,
                thread_title,
                thread_description,
                thread_icon
            ) VALUES (
                '$_SESSION[user_id]',
                '$_GET[f]',
                '$date',
                '$date',
                '$_POST[topictitle]',
                '$_POST[topicdescription]',
                '$_POST[posticon]'
            )
        ";
        $thread_query = @mysqli_query ($db_connect, $thread_sql);
```

Comment: You don't say what language or framework you're using.  In straight SQL, you do INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('a', NULL)

Comment: this is more of a PHP problem, not a mysql problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like this (PDO):

```
$stmt  = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO foo(bar) values (?);');
$stmt->execute(array($value=='NULL'? NULL,$value));
```

Or with `mysql`:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO foo(bar) 
   values ('.($value=='NULL'? 'NULL',"'".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'").')';
```

Comment: this is a far more robust and secure way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 4):

With MySQL:

```
insert into your_table (nulled_column) values (null);
```

If you are getting a `'NULL'` literal instead of a `null` value, it's probably because you are not issuing the right command from your client (PHP, C#, Java program). You will need to share the code you are using for your insertion in order to get more help.

UPDATE:

According to your recently edited question, just get rid of the `''` when you are inserting NULL values. If you use `''`, then you'll get `'NULL'` literals inserted as you mentioned.

I would also suggest you use `PreparedStatements` in MySQL in order to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score -2):

This works. Had to use an IF

```
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $thread_sql = "
            INSERT INTO forum_threads (
                user_id,
                forum_id,
                thread_postdate,
                thread_lastpost,
                thread_title,
                thread_description,
                thread_icon
            ) VALUES (
                '$_SESSION[user_id]',
                '$_GET[f]',
                '$date',
                '$date',
                '$_POST[topictitle]',
                '$_POST[topicdescription]',
                IF('$_POST[posticon]'='NULL',NULL,'$_POST[posticon]')
            )
        ";
        $thread_query = @mysqli_query ($db_connect, $thread_sql);
```

Comment: this leaves you wide open to SQL Injection, and I will be happy to hax0r your db. Use prepared statements. Sanitize your user inputs. This is WRONG. NEVER, EVER, EVER take direct user input from $_SESSION and $_POST variables!